# State array not updating in child component loop - array is overwritten

Tags: reactjs, arrays, sockets, react-hooks, state

I have a very interesting problem.

I am building a game that has 9 grids(arrays) that also has 9 grids (arrays) inside.

The way I am rendering the board is this way:

```
function MainComponent() {
// state declaration and logic here
const [mainBoard, setMainBoard] = useState(
    new Array(9).fill({ val: null, disabled: false })
  );

return (
    {mainBoard.map((mainSquare, key) => {
          return (
            <MiniBoard/>
          );
        })}
```

and when each MiniBoard component is called, it creates a miniBoard array inside.

```
 const [miniBoard, setMiniBoard] = useState(
    new Array(9).fill({ val: null, disabled: false })
  );
```

Then this miniBoard array is looped to display the inner square, where the user clicks to make a turn.

The board is created properly. I created a local player, where 2 players could play the game.

The problem:

When I shifted to introducing a multiplayer option using sockets, the miniBoard array is not updating properly.
Whenever a user clicks on a miniBoard item (smallest square), a click is registered and the 'turn' is taken place. I am sending the 'turn value' and 'index' through socket and sending over to the 2nd player.

The values reach the 2nd player as expected but it updates/overwrites the miniBoard array.
The click happens in the inner loop because we need to update the miniBoard, on a click.

In local, i wasn't getting this problem because I believe React has a reference that whenever the event occurs in a loop it has the index and only updates the corresponding state in the loop.

```
// this is inside the MiniBoard componenet
 useEffect(() => {   
socket.on("turnTaken", (obj) => {
      var currentIndex = obj.currentIndex;
      var turnType = obj.turnType;
      var mainBoardTurnLocation = obj.turnLocation;
      var mainBoardCurrentIndex = obj.mainCurrentIndex;

      if (mainBoardTurnLocation === mainCurrentIndex) {
        const updatedminiBoard = {
          ...miniBoard[currentIndex],
          val: turnType,
          disabled: true,
        };
        
        // !! The miniBoard here is always the previous for the next player.

        const newMiniBoard = miniBoard.slice();
        newMiniBoard[currentIndex] = updatedminiBoard;
        console.log(newMiniBoard);
        setTurnLocation(currentIndex);
        setMiniBoard(newMiniBoard);

        if (turnType === "x") {
          setTurn(player2);
        } else {
          setTurn(player1);
        }
      }
    });
  }, [socket]);
```

This is how I am listening for the socket when a turn is taken.
the if condition that checks for 'mainBoardTurnLocation === mainCurrentIndex', is what I tried to make sure that it only updates the current index of the MainBoard, otherwise it would update all the MiniBoard arrays as it is running in a loop and it would run this 9 times. But even after this, the newMiniBoard created is always overwritten by the previous. I believe there must be something in React to solve this that I don't know.

The comment in the above code snippet:
**The miniBoard here is always the previous for the next player.**

When player1 takes a turn, the current MiniBoard is updated.
If player2 takes a turn in another MiniBoard, the board is updated as expected.
But if the player2 takes a turn in the same MiniBoard, the change from player1 is not registered and it overwrites his move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you haven't added values in dependency list of useEffect.
state variables in useEffect doesn't updated if you don't add these in dependency list.
In other words, miniBoard in useEffect will be always initial value in your code.
Hope it could be helpful for you. Cheers

Ps. And I recommend to add code to remove listener to avoid multiple registration of event listener.

```
useEffect(() => {   
const handleTurnTaken = (obj) => {
      var currentIndex = obj.currentIndex;
      var turnType = obj.turnType;
      var mainBoardTurnLocation = obj.turnLocation;
      var mainBoardCurrentIndex = obj.mainCurrentIndex;

      if (mainBoardTurnLocation === mainCurrentIndex) {
        const updatedminiBoard = {
          ...miniBoard[currentIndex],
          val: turnType,
          disabled: true,
        };
        
        // !! The miniBoard here is always the previous for the next player.

        const newMiniBoard = miniBoard.slice();
        newMiniBoard[currentIndex] = updatedminiBoard;
        console.log(newMiniBoard);
        setTurnLocation(currentIndex);
        setMiniBoard(newMiniBoard);

        if (turnType === "x") {
          setTurn(player2);
        } else {
          setTurn(player1);
        }
      }
    }
socket.on("turnTaken", handleTurnTaken);
return () => {
socket.off("turnTaken", handleTurnTaken);
}
  }, [socket, miniBoard]);
```